# How to make httplib2 cache readonly?

Tags: python, caching, cache-control, httplib2

The following code creates Http object with caching enabled:

```
http = httplib2.Http('cache')
r, b = http.request('http://google.com')
```

The following code creates Http object with caching enabled and if the resource has already been in the cache, its never requested again:

```
http = httplib2.Http('cache')
r, b = http.request('http://google.com',
        headers={'cache-control':'min-fresh=-1000000000'})
```

How do I modify these two samples for the `cache` is used but never updated?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I want to cache a few pages and then disable caching to save disk space and io time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a cache into the `Http` object you construct, if it implements [these methods](http://bitworking.org/projects/httplib2/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#id2):

> ```
> Cache.get(key)
> Cache.set(key, value)
> Cache.delete(key)
> ```

Wrap an instance of [`FileCache`](http://bitworking.org/projects/httplib2/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#httplib2.FileCache) with an object that you retain a reference to. After your initial requests, change its behaviour so that `get` continues to work and `set` delegates to `delete` (so you never return a stale value).